# Translating "Surah ali imran" to French

Tags: traduction, arabe

What is the translation of "*Surah ali imran*" to French?

*ali imran* (the family of Imran) is a chapter in the Quran (the holy book of muslims).

Comment: you need to add more informations and details to your question ...

Comment: http://www.al-hamdoulillah.com/coran/lire/sourate-3.html.

Answer (score 3):

The usual name of this surah in French is *La famille de 'Imrân*. Please do a minimum amount of reasearch. It took me all of 30 seconds to find that out.

Comment: I see it written *'Îmran* on Wikipedia. Have you seen it written differently somewhere else?

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sourate lists it as *'Imrân*. I'm not fmailiar with Arabic, but the original name of the surah is consistently transliterated with a long *a* everywhere I look. I would rather ask on the ['Îmran talk page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:%27%C3%8Emran) why the article uses that spelling.